# Crystal Reports is grouping by default

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a crystal report with three columns. I want to display all the records and a total in the last row. However, my crystal report is grouping by default. I am confused

This is how I do it in the CR.

[image]

This is how it shows 
[image]

Thi sis how i wanted

[image]

I want everything in a single table and a one toal for each. Why is it grouping this way? Any help would be appreciated.

- EDITED

Below is how i arrived at the TOTAL 
Formulas

O/S BALANCE := amount - collected.

OSBALANCE TOTAL := SUM{@O?S BALANCE});

COLLECTED TOTAL := SUM({colection})

Comment: give the formulas you placed in report and also where did you palced the total and detail feilds

Comment: Thank you SIva. I use formulas for the collected and OS BALANCE total as above. Thank you

Comment: where did you place `OSBalance` and `Collection` in report.

Comment: The report file is the first image sir. You can see OSBALANCE is in the second column while the OSBALANCE total in the 2nd column and thrid row. The collection is placed in the third column collected. The image is there sir. Thank you

Comment: See that is where it makes the difference in crystal reports. I will suggest one thing place `OSBalance` in detail and put the total in report footer and let me know the result

Comment: WHEN i PUT IN THE footer then it does not display the total

Comment: I can see formulas are corect may be you need to check the query what data it is retriving I suspect that one is the issue.

Comment: Sorry , when i put the total in report footer, now the total shows however the DEtail is not showing.

Comment: Dont do any calculations just place the field and see whether it is showing full data or not

Comment: Its ok Sivva. Your first answer works for me. "I will suggest one thing place OSBalance in detail and put the total in report footer". That works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: You can rewrite that and will select as the right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See that is where it makes the difference in crystal reports. I will suggest one thing place OSBalance in detail and put the total in report footer and let me know the result

Answer (score 1):

Add a cross-tab object to the report's `footer` section.  Use the `OS BALANCE` field for the rows field and the `COLLECTED` for the summarized field.